# How to change audio language whilst keeping English text?

Tags: pc, dmc-devil-may-cry

How do you change the audio language of the PC version of Devil May Cry while keeping the English text? I've done this for Skyrim but I'm not sure how to do this for DmC. I know I can go into Steam and change the language of the game, but that will change the text as well. I've been trying to play games with a different audio dub but keeping the English caption to feel refreshed. Feels like playing a new game.